# About some self-adjoint operators

Tags: operator-theory

Let us consider the linear operator
$$A(f(x,y))=B(f(x,y))+iy=\begin{bmatrix}B(f(x,y)) & -y\\y & B(f(x,y))\end{bmatrix}$$

written in the matricial form, where $B(f(x,y))$ is also a linear opertor whose values are real. Here $f$ is complex valued function.

From the properties of matrices we have

$$(B(f(x,y))-iy)^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}B(f(x,y)) & y\\-y & B(f(x,y))\end{bmatrix}^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}B(f(x,y)) & -y\\y & B(f(x,y))\end{bmatrix}=A(f(x,y)).....................(*)$$
Then the operator $A$ is self adjoint.

My question is: What is the set of functions and the inner product must be used in which the equation $(*)$ is true.

Comment: Your notation here is rather confusing, can you make a more standard presentation?

Comment: @Ian: Yes.Done.

Comment: That wasn't the problem. The problem is that it's not clear what's real vs. complex vs. matrix, and that you are using transpose when you mean adjoint (and not even conjugate transpose, but a general adjoint). It's also not clear what the significance of the $x,y$ dependence is, since the self-adjointness seems to not depend on that.

Comment: @Ian: The operator $B$ is real.

Comment: So $B(f(x,y))$ is just a real number for each pair of real numbers $x,y$? In that case again there is no point in having $f$ at all, unless there is some significance to the $x,y$ dependence that I am not seeing.

Comment: @Ian: Yes. This is the case.

Comment: @Ian: An operator is acting on a set of functions.

Comment: But again I'm not seeing the point: if $B(f(x,y))$ is a real number for each $x,y$ and there is no connection between the point where $A$ is calculated and its action on a vector, then $A$ is never self-adjoint because it is skew-symmetric and therefore has pure imaginary eigenvalues. It would be self-adjoint in, say, the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{C}^2$ if you had $-iy$ and $iy$ in the off-diagonal entries.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to ask when $A$ is self-adjoint *as a function of $f$*, rather than when $A(f(x,y))$ (a matrix) is self-adjoint? Again your notation here is confusing.

Comment: @Ian: Yes. this is the question.